# jQuery Inline Editing for date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

On my page, there are multiple places with date fields rendered as below;
So some date are always displayed in editable text boxes and other as labels (then inline-edited)

```
<div class="editableDateTxt" title="06/04/2014">06/04/2011</div>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="date1" id="date1" class="datePicker">
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="date2" id="date2" class="datePicker">

<div class="editableDateTxt" title="06/04/2014">06/04/2012</div>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="date3" id="date3" class="datePicker">

<div class="editableDateTxt" title="06/04/2014">06/04/2013</div>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="date4" id="date4" class="datePicker">
```

Now I need to implement inline editing...i.e. when label is clicked, I want to show the jQuery UI date picker and on blur, I want to hide...

So I am using the below code;

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
                        var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
                        $(this).parent().append(input);
                        $(this).remove();
                        input.focus();
                        $('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker('show');
                });

                $(document).on("blur",".datePicker", function () {
                        $(this).parent().append($("<div class='editableDateTxt'/>").html($(this).val()));
                        $(this).remove();
                });
```

However, there seems to be an issue with the line;

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker('show');
```

since there are multiple elements with class datePicker...How do I ensure that the datepicker is shown only where the div element with class "editableDateTxt" is clicked ?

---

Tried onSelect code

I updated the code as below, but nothing happens on select (i even tried adding an alert inside onSelect, but it does not fire)

```
$(parent).find('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
        parent.append($("<div class='editableDateTxt'/>").html(date));
        $(this).remove();
    }
}).datepicker('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem 100%. But wouldn't just using `$(this).find()` solve your problem. See below:

<strike>$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
        var input = $('', {'type': 'text', 'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
        $(this).find('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker('show');
    });</strike>

I re-read your code. What about storing a reference to the parent and using that to search.

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
    $(parent).find('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker('show');
});
```

Or do all the elements share the same parent. Bit unsure as your JS seems to suggest unique parent elements, but your HTML doesn't. You may not have included all your HTML though.

Of course, just using the input variable would also work:

```
input.datepicker().datepicker('show');
```

Didn't notice that one at first.

---

Responding to your comment about closing the datepicker and just showing the selected date. Best way for this is to use the `onSelect` option in the datepicker. Like this:

```
parent.find('.datePicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
        parent.append($("<div class='editableDateTxt'/>").html(date));
        $(this).remove();
    }
}).datepicker('show');
```

See this working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6pptH/

---

So your entire JS becomes:

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
    parent.find('.datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            parent.append($("<div class='editableDateTxt'/>").html(date));
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }).datepicker('show');
});
```

Comment: If I've misunderstood your problem, can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate it?

Comment: you seem to have understood well...but the issue is that $(this).find('.datePicker') does not fetch the selected element...may be as i m using $(this).remove(); above

Comment: @testndtv sorry. I now realise I misread some of your code. I'll have another look.

Comment: @testndtv added another possible solution. Let me know if it doesn't fit with your html though.

Comment: Hey...thx a lot...the code now works fine...there are unique parent elements...it would be great if u could help me in one more thing...

Comment: once the date is selected, the date appears in text box...but can i just show the selected date as static label (i.e. in a div)...that div would have class "editableDateTxt"...so when it is clicked again, i would show datepicker...hope i m not confusing u...

Comment: @testndtv Put it in jsfiddle and saw your problem. Have updated answer to show a solution for it. Hope that sorts everything for you.

Comment: Thx a lot...while it works as expect on your jsfiddle, it is not working for me...i just updated the code i tried in my orig question..

Comment: @testndtv What version of jquery and jquery-ui are you using? Or can you try to recreate the error on jsfiddle so I can see the problem.

Comment: jQuery v1.9.0 and jQuery UI - v1.10.0 - 2013-02-13

Comment: @testndtv I've updated fiddle to use your versions of jquery and jquery-ui and all still works well. http://jsfiddle.net/6pptH/1/ The problem must be somewhere else in the code. Please check that your have copied my code exactly. Maybe try posting your full html in a jsfiddle so I can see that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker('show');
```

try:

```
input.datepicker().datepicker('show');
```